# How do I run a simultaneous scan in nmap?

Tags: networking, tcp, nmap

I am trying to run a simultaneous nmap scan to do the following

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7skvt.png

I have divided what I need to do into 2 parts

nmap -sN -p 21-25,80,139,8080

nmap -T 5 -sU -p 53,11 thevictim.com/16

How do I run them as a simultaneous scan? Also, are my above commands okay?

Thanks

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: I'm only looking for help with nmap commands, where would you suggest I ask then, I think this is the best place.

Comment: I've also tried to do it myself and have some what succeeded

Comment: https://nmap.org/book/man-port-specification.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, nmap will simultaneously scan 36 sockets. The **--max_parallelism** option can be set to 1 to scan a single port at a time. The minimum possible value for --max_parallelism is 1, and nmap will warn if the requested value is above 900. You can use this option for scan multiple hosts.

Comment: There is a way to scan more than 36 sockets?